# How to reset a sum value bound to a textBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi i have a TextBlock and its Text property is bound to a ViewModel property (Total tickets Price) i want to make a button that helps me reset both the data and the textBlock to 0.

i tried setting the Total to 0 but i encounter a StackOverflowException.

I am learning WPF so please bare my question if it is very novice!

**TicketViewModel**

```
 public ObservableCollection<TicketModel> TicketsEnVente { get; set; }
    public TicketViewModel()
    {
        TicketsEnVente = new ObservableCollection<TicketModel>();
        TicketsEnVente.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Total");
    }


    public float Total
    {
        get { return TicketsEnVente.Sum(x =>x.Prix); }
        set
        {
            Total = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**Xaml**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Total"  Text="{Binding Total}"/>
```

Comment: Aside from the core issue of your question (the StackOverflowException), the (attempted) logic of your Total property is rather questionable. If some code would assign Total like `Total = 5.3f;`, one would expect Total having the value of 5.3. However, immediately after assigning 5.3 to Total, trying to read/get the value back from Total like `var x = Total;`, the variable `x` will not contain the value 5.3 that has been assigned to the Total property, but some completely different value. Ergo, your program logic with respect to the Total property is completely broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting StackOverflowException because you infinitely call setter of Total property. Introduce a private field to avoid that problem. Your logic is fine, now setting Total to 0 should refresh bound view.

```
    private float total;
    public float Total
    {
        get { return TicketsEnVente.Sum(x =>x.Prix); }
        set
        {
            total = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        }

    }
```

Note that you probably want your button to clear your data collection and then trigger OnPropertyChanged(Total).

```
public void ResetData()
{
    TicketsEnVente.Clear();
    OnPropertyChanged("Total");
}
```

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks!